# Color TD in tables with rowspan and colspan

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html-table

I'm trying to color some TDs in my table. But it doesn't work as intended, as it colors other TDs, as well. Here, I tried to color the second TD:

[image]

The problem seems to be that I'm using colspans and rowspans.

This is my code:

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $('table tr td:nth-child(2)').css("background-color", "red");
});
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/devqnyg5/).

*Please note, this is a simplified example. My real table is bigger and more complex. It won't be enough to just color all cells containing `B` and `2`.*

Comment: If I understand you want to colorize all the 2nd column ?
If yes, there is no selector for this, and it's not so simple to know in which column is a TD. You have to do an algo to calculate the position of your TD.

Comment: what are you trying to do? Do you want to change colors alternating columns? B and its rows, D and its rows, ect... isn't?

Comment: @AlessandroMaglioccola I'm trying to find the right selector for a column(s). In this example, I tried to color the second TD, so `B` and `2`. The `4` has been colored mistakenly.

Comment: Accept an answer please so that this question can be considered solved..!

Answer (score 0):

```
$("button").click(function() {
  $('table>thead>tr>td:eq(1),table>tbody>tr>td:eq(1)').css("background-color",  "red");
});
```

Hope this helps..

Comment: That only works in this simple example. When I add another row at the bottom, it will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you are trying to do If I am correct as :

**WITH USE OF `<colgroup>` Tag :**

**HTML :**

```
  <table border="1">
  <colgroup>
  <colgroup>
  <colgroup span="2">
  <colgroup>
  <tr>
    <th scope="colgroup">A</th>
    <th scope="colgroup">B</th>
    <th colspan="2"  scope="colgroup">C</th>
    <th scope="colgroup">D</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="3">1</td>
    <td rowspan="3">2</td>
    <td rowspan="3">3</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>3</td>
    <td>4</td>
    <td>4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<button class="col1">Col 1</button>
<button class="col2">Col 2</button>
<button class="col3">Col 3</button>
<button class="col4">Col 4</button>
<button class="reload">Reload</button>
```

**JS :**

```
$(".col1").click(function() {
$('colgroup:nth-child(1)').css("background-color", "red");
});

$(".col2").click(function() {
  $('colgroup:nth-child(2)').css("background-color", "red");
});

$(".col3").click(function() {
  $('colgroup:nth-child(3)').css("background-color", "red");
});

$(".col4").click(function() {
  $('colgroup:nth-child(4)').css("background-color", "red");
});

$(".reload").click(function() {
 location.reload();
});
```

> **COLGROUP Method Fiddle Link :** https://jsfiddle.net/devqnyg5/11/

**WITH USE OF `<col>` Tag :**

**HTML :**

```
    <table border="1">
      <col>
      <col>
      <col>
      <col>
      <col> 
        <tr>
            <th>A</th>
            <th>B</th>
            <th colspan="2">C</th>
            <th>D</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td rowspan="3">1</td>
            <td rowspan="3">2</td>
            <td rowspan="3">3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
    </table><br>
    <button class="col1">Col 1</button> 
    <button class="col2">Col 2</button> 
    <button class="col3">Col 3</button> 
    <button class="col4">Col 4</button> 
    <button class="reload">Reload</button>
```

**JS :**

```
 $(".col1").click(function() {
  $('col:nth-child(1)').css("background-color", "red");
});

$(".col2").click(function() {
  $('col:nth-child(2)').css("background-color", "red");
});

$(".col3").click(function() {
  $('col:nth-child(3),col:nth-child(4)').css("background-color", "red");
});

$(".col4").click(function() {
  $('col:nth-child(5)').css("background-color", "red");
});

$(".reload").click(function() {
 location.reload();
});
```

> **COL Method Fiddle Link :** https://jsfiddle.net/devqnyg5/9/

Comment: That only works in this simple example. When I add another row at the bottom, it will be ignored.

Comment: Yes...working on that...Will let you know soon then..!

Comment: Updated the post...! Besides still if you are looking for a dynamic way so the way which pops up in my mind right now is to write dynamic js code with use of this PHP API as : http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Updated the post with two methods...Use whatever you feel more better..! :D :P Enjoy..!

Answer (score -2):

Check that it doesn't contain the col-span:

```
$('table tr td:nth-child(2):not([col-span]), table tr td:nth-child(2):not([row-span])')
```

Comment: I doesn't help.